# why I can't pop the last view in the navigation stack?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I want to pop the last view in my app, so I'm calling this function:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and self is the last view controller, I expect that the app will exit, but that does't happen why ?

Comment: Are you saying that you are intentionally trying to exit from the app by popping a view controller?

Comment: exactly, that last view controller

Comment: It is not possible to exit an application manually.

Comment: Ah, that's new to me, however that may be because as gran33 says "it is not common in iOS". Why would you want functionality within an app to exit, when that it what the home button is for?

Comment: With regards [[NSThread mainThread] exit], the documentation says "Invoking this method should be avoided as it does not give your thread a chance to clean up any resources it allocated during its execution."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to exit your app, just do that:

```
[[NSThread mainThread] exit]
```

Anyway, your way:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

It's common in `android`, not in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

For going to the rootView u need to call as below,

```
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // Returns the root/last vie controller.
```

and the one u used is below,

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // Returns the popped controller.
```

Comment: but the current view is the root view controller,so I want to pop the root view controller !

Comment: U can exit the app but can't remove/pop root view controller. Also what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: when I send push notification to the app, and the user tap on the notification, then my app launches and open a view controller, so in this case I want the user to exit the app when he press the back key?

Comment: Then just press the home button?

Comment: Just write this `exit(0);` this will exit ur app.

Comment: @david ur welcome and was there any info missing in my post just my my improvement.